# Dijkstra's Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: sorting, quicksort

How does Dijkstra's Quicksort Algorithm perform better than the original Quicksort Algorithm in terms of memory usage,number of exchanges made and time taken?

- original quicksort refers to Tony Hoare's quicksort

[image]

Comment: Think about its performance on a sequence of all 1's.

Comment: That would be worst case since it has to compare the 1s unnecessarily. Am I right?